# sox convert to spectogram parameters meaning

Tags: sox

Here, I want to use `sox` to convert flac file into spectogram png file. When I want to convert `.flac` file, I can use the following command

```
sox output.flac -n spectrogram -r -o a.png
```

And if I want to convert into N x 129 pixels spectogram, I can use the following command

```
sox output.flac -n spectrogram -Y 200 -X 50 -m -r -o spectogram.png
```

However, I don't quite understand totally what `-Y 200` and `-X 50` parameters mean i.e. is there a way that I can convert these parameters into sampling frequency, time bin (in millisecond) and also frequency bin as in Matlab or Python. It would be great if someone can answer here in details since the documentation in [chirlu/sox](https://github.com/chirlu/sox) does not state clearly what it means (or I didn't find it explicitly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official [sox manual](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) describes the parameters in full and the source code is here [spectrogram.c](https://sourceforge.net/p/sox/code/ci/master/tree/src/spectrogram.c#l139).

But briefly:

> −X num:
>
> X-axis pixels/second; the default is auto-calculated to fit the given
>   or known audio duration to the X-axis size, or 100 otherwise. If given
>   in conjunction with −d, this option affects the width of the
>   spectrogram; otherwise, it affects the duration of the spectrogram.
>   num can be from 1 (low time resolution) to 5000 (high time resolution)
>   and need not be an integer.

and

> -Y num:
>
> Sets the target total height of the spectrogram(s). The default value is 550
>   pixels. Using this option (and by default), SoX will
>   choose a height for individual spectrogram channels that is one more
>   than a power of two, so the actual total height may fall short of the
>   given number.

For `-X 50`, the horizontal time resolution is:

```
dt = 1000/50 = 20 ms/pixel
```

For `-Y 200` the largest power of 2 less than 200 is 128. Assuming a sampling rate of 44.1 kHz, the frequency resolution is:

```
bin_size = 44100/128 = 344.5 Hz
```

Comment: I just noticed that `-Y` will select the frequency range falls in `2^n`. That's why it goes to 128 but not 50.